# Not allowing draw on button in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am new to JavaFX.

Please have a look at attached image where i want to restrict drawing on button.
And please also suggest me for printing to printer.

(In swing, it is possible with PrintJob and Toolkit class)

Below is my code :

```
public class PrintScribble extends Application {

private short last_x = 0, last_y = 0;              // last click posistion
private Vector lines = new Vector(256, 256);        // store the scribble
private Properties printprefs = new Properties();  // store user preferences
private Path path;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("PrintScribble");

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    bp.setMinWidth(scene.getWidth());
    Button b = new Button("Print");
    bp.setRight(b);

    root.getChildren().add(bp);

    b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Printer call");
            //print();
        }
    });

    path = new Path();

    scene.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseDragged(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseExited(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseMoved(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(mouseHandler);
    scene.setOnMouseReleased(mouseHandler);

    root.getChildren().add(path);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            path.getElements()
                    .add(new MoveTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            path.getElements()
                    .add(new LineTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
        }
    }
};

/**
 * The main method. Create a PrintScribble() object and away we go!
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want the drawing to restrict on. Further you are asking two different question. You might have more success when posing them separately, as they are not related.

Comment: please see the image, i am able to draw using mouse over the button, which i want restrict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            path.getElements()
                    .add(new MoveTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            path.getElements()
                    .add(new LineTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
        }

        // Here is an answer
        path.toBack();

    }
```

Comment: I think just calling `path.toBack` once from `start` should be enough.  Shouldn't have to repeatedly call it...